# how to style a article with separate horizontal sections

Tags: jquery, css

I have used jquery to create a simple slideup/down effect when user clicks on the title of the article, the article slides down.

I want to style the article to make it visually appealing(because its text after text). I am just finding my feet with new css3 concepts.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: this is very general question, try to be more specific... what do you want as visual appealing?

Comment: sorry, I want to make it simple and easy to read.

Comment: A live example or screenshot of what you have would help us a great deal :) Also, this would be a better wuestion for www.doctype.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you' ll get a proper answer here for layout but some redirections to other websites:

try these to get some inspiration:

- http://www.sixrevisions.com/
- http://css-tricks.com
- http://thinkvitamin.com

there are other websites or blogs giving hints an tricks on those kind of things, try to find those to get a good idea on how to make a good design for your website/blog